# How to send an ampersand in a Oracle database query string containing xml

Tags: xml, oracle, http

Before anyone marks as duplicate, I've done my due diligence on Stack and Google. There is a common question about sending special characters through XML, this is not that question.

The thing that makes this unique is I am sending a string variable to an Oracle database that contains XML. here is an example of what I am sending.

```
string=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <value>Stack&Overflow</value>
</request>
```

if you run this through an XML validator, it will return as badly formed as the "string=" portion is not included in the XML. however, the Oracle database requires this type of precursor to read the XML 'file'/string.

there are 5 characters you must escape in XML, for the ampersand "&" the best practice is `&amp;` however, the string I am sending above is not XML, but only contains XML.

my application allows creation of data containing the "&" character, but then I can't use that via the API.

Since Oracle is a popular platform..has anyone overcome a XML request error like this?

things to note:
-the application works flawlessly aside from this special character issue. I get 200's all day with descriptive XML responses. 
-the application has error handling, but I don't even get a 200 response with error when I send "&", only a HTML 400 response.

I'm using javascript, but I am testing in Postman, so there is really no specific language, just a basic HTTP XML issue. feel free to edit tags as needed and thanks for the help in advance.

it's a POST if anyone is curious. this is the correct method per the documentation and what is used on all requests that are successful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "sending a string variable to an Oracle database". You're sending it via an HTTP POST request... to what? What web server is receiving your request and translating it into SQL requests? Or please link to the documentation you're using.

Comment: kfinity, your background looks good for this question. thanks for stopping by. 

`string=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <value>Stack&Overflow</value>
</request>`

i am under the impression that this is not XML, but instead contains XML. so this would be the body of my request. 

the Oracle server is
Oracle-Application-Server-10g

Comment: Ok great, so Oracle Application Server is your container server. Do you know what application it's running that you're connecting to? Maybe if you edit your question to include more of the POST request than just the `string=` part, it would make more sense.

Comment: there are security concerns so I am attempting to summarize. I don't have access inside the Oracle server, its 3rd party. a partner site. the string is actually very short as well, there is a variable name and an equals sign. there is the same <?xml..> header tag, then there is a parent tag and a few child tags in it for authentication. i know that if this was pure XML the CDATA or "$amp;" options might work. because it is an Oracle server interpreting my input doc, represented by "string=<?xml..." i figure it is interpreting a different way